# Identifying and changing the Bullet type in PowerPoint using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to figure out how to identify bullet type and change it, i. e. check whether bullets used in whole presentation are square shaped bullets. If not, a macro should change the bullet type to square.

Example : In this picture, I would like to change round shapes bullets to square shaped bullets throughout the slide deck.

[image: Bullet conversion]

Answer (score 2):

The other 2 replies are adequate if the bullets have been created using only local formatting. If the presentation is a normal one, where the bullets are set in the slide master, those round bullets will keep coming back like a bad smell. Instead, change the bullets to square on the slide master, then reset all slides to force an update. This sets levels 1, 3 and 5 to square bullets:

```
Sub ChangeSomeBullets()
  Dim oSlide As Slide
  Dim oShape As Shape

  For Each oShape In ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.Shapes
    If oShape.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
      If oShape.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderBody Then
        For X = 1 To oShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs.Count
          Select Case X
            Case 1, 3, 5
              With oShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(X).ParagraphFormat.Bullet
                .Font.Name = "Wingdings"
                .Character = 167
              End With
          End Select
        Next X
      End If
    End If
  Next oShape
  For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    oSlide.CustomLayout = oSlide.CustomLayout
  Next oSlide
End Sub
```

Comment: Thinking about the slide master is a good idea (+1 for that), but resetting *every* bullet and reassigning *every* CustomLayout maybe not.

Comment: oSlide.CustomLayout = oSlide.CustomLayout does not reassign layouts. It's the VBA equivalent of clicking the Reset button in the user interface. After making changes to a master, you normally have to Reset slides to update the slide to the new formatting.

Answer (score 0):

They don't make it easy. You need to change the `BulletFormat.Character` property to the Unicode number of the shape you want. Here's what I did: I have a presentation where the second slide is Title and Content (two shapes). In the Content section I have four bullets. I changed the first one from the shape it is to the shape I want and run this:

```
Public Sub ChangeBullets()

    Dim para As TextRange

    For Each para In ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs
        Debug.Print para.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Character, Left(para.Text, 20)
    Next para

    ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(1).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Character = 9642

End Sub
```

This loops through the four bullets (para) in the second shape of the second slide and prints to the immediate window the character of the bullet followed by a little of the text (to make sure I was where I think I was). That produced:

```
 111          Reality    
 9642         Consistency
 9642         No Shortcuts
 9642         The Right Tool
```

That tells me the bullet used to be 9642 (the same as its brothers) and I manually changed it to 111. Now that I know the Unicode number, I could loop through every slide, every shape, every paragraph and change the bullet number.

In the last line, I change the bullet back to 9642 just to make sure I could (and it worked).

Answer (score 0):

You may play with this to see the parameters of your bullets.

I added some examples to explain how to set font, character, color etc.

```
Private Sub UnderstandAndChangeBullets()
    Dim i As Integer

    ' loop through paragraphs of a shape:
    With Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(5).Shapes(1).TextFrame
        For i = 1 To .TextRange.Paragraphs.Count
            With .TextRange.Paragraphs(i).ParagraphFormat.Bullet
                If .Type = ppBulletUnnumbered Then
                    Debug.Print "Size: " & .RelativeSize,    ' 1, 1.25, ...
                    Debug.Print "Color: " & .Font.Color.RGB, ' 0, RGB(255, 0, 0), vbRed, ...
                    Debug.Print "Font: " & .Font.Name,       ' Arial, Wingdings, Symbol, ...
                    Debug.Print "Character: " & .Character   ' 8226, 111, 167, 118, ...
                End If
            End With
        Next i
    End With

    ' ... or work with selected text:
    With Application.ActiveWindow.Selection
        If .Type = ppSelectionText Then
            For i = 1 To .TextRange.Paragraphs.Count
                ' ... like above
            Next i
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```